# Create a time series with daily frequency in R

Tags: r

I'm confused whether or not R's ts class supports daily frequencies. `ts` has an argument `start`. But from the docs `start` can take a number or a vector with 2 values like `c(2014, 1)`. How could I tell it to start on January 1st, 2014? How about January 2nd?

Here is my code that gets a file and tries to make a TS with daily frequency from it.

```
# Get data. 
my_data = read.csv("time series test.csv", header = TRUE)
```

head(my_data) outputs this:

```
  Date    Value
1 1/1/14 123.0000
2 1/2/14 128.5693
3 1/3/14 129.1474
4 1/4/14 130.1361
5 1/5/14 137.9758
6 1/6/14 141.0548
```

Now I'll construct a ts from it.

```
# Get start date.
start_date = as.Date(my_data[1,1], '%m/%d/%y')

# Create a time series
# At this step, what value should I use for the `start` argument? 
my_ts = ts(my_data[,2], start=c(2009, 1), frequency=7)

# Plot it
plot(my_ts)

# Get a STL fit
fit = stl(my_ts, s.window="period")

# Plot stl fit
plot(fit)
```

Comment: Is this only realistically doable using another library, like Zoo?

Comment: With `ts`, set the `frequency` to 365. You have to skip February 29 in order to use `stl()`.

Comment: Thanks Pascal, I'll give it a try. What value should go in "start"?

Comment: When I use stl, I get this error still `Error in stl(my_ts, s.window = "period") : series is not periodic or has less than two periods`

Comment: You only have 2014 as year? If yes, you cannot apply `stl()`.

Comment: Why can I not apply stl() if I only have the year 2014? I still have multiple periods (weeks) in the dataset.

Comment: `stl()` cannot decompose the signal with only 1 year of data. You might find some hints in [this page](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9506/stl-trend-of-time-series-using-r)